# Why are values in callback function different - bad?

Tags: c, windows, callback, gtk, parameter-passing

Very simple application - You can copy - paste - run.
In main is just "creating" application. - here is not problem (probably)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk\gtk.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int *p;
}struct_int;

static void test_fce(gpointer data){

    struct_int *local =  (struct_int *)data;
    printf("\n");
    printf("local %p\n", local);
    printf("local a %i\n", local->a);
    printf("local &a %p\n", &(local->a));
    (local->a)++;
    printf("local p %p\n", local->p );
    printf("local &p %p\n", &(local->p));
    printf("local *p %i\n", *(local->p));
    (*(local->p))++;

 }


 static void write_value(GtkButton *button,
                                      gpointer data)
 {

    struct_int *local = (struct_int *)data;
    printf("\n");
    printf("local %p\n",local);
    printf("local a %i\n", local->a);
    printf("local &a %p\n", &(local->a));
    printf("local p %p\n", local->p );
    printf("local &p %p\n", &(local->p));
    printf("local *p %i\n", *(local->p));

 }

 static void activate (GtkApplication*   app,
                                gpointer             user_data)
{
    int i = 7;
    GtkWidget *main_window, *button;
    struct_int test_struct;

    main_window = gtk_application_window_new (app);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Start");
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), button);

    gtk_widget_show_all (main_window);


    test_struct.a = 5;
    test_struct.p = &i;

    printf("i %i\n",i);
    printf("&i %p\n",&i);

    printf("test_struct_p& %p\n", &test_struct);
    printf("test_struct_p a %i\n", test_struct.a);
    printf("test_struct_p &a %p\n", &(test_struct.a));
    printf("test_struct_p p %p\n", test_struct.p);
    printf("test_struct_p &p %p\n", &(test_struct.p));
    printf("test_struct_p *p %i\n", *(test_struct.p));


    test_fce((gpointer) &test_struct);
    test_fce((gpointer) &test_struct);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (write_value), (gpointer) &test_struct);
    test_fce((gpointer) &test_struct);
}

int main (int    argc,
           char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    app = gtk_application_new ("a.b.my_app", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);



    return status;
}
```

When I run application - it print 3 times output of function "test_fce" in expected way ( some adress and correct value of variables).

But when I clicked on Button, all printed adress are corect (same as in test_fce) but
value of "a" is bad (seems to be always 0),
value of "p"  is bad (seems to be always 000000...)
so on line where I try to access to "*p" program fall down.

What is wrong with code?

EDIT: And what is "the best" way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using automatic storage class variables from function `activate` after the function has returned, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Than you for quick response :-) As I edit main question - what is the best way to fix it? I took this construction from example on official website of gtk, so I expect it is not absolutely unuseable...

Comment: You will need to allocate `test_struct` on the heap using `g_malloc()` (ergo the variable must also be a pointer, and thus you don't pass `&test_struct` to `g_signal_connect()`). It is up to you to call `g_free()` when you no longer need it, but not in `activate()`.

Comment: Yes, `test_struct` and `i` are the automatic storage class variables from the `activate` function that are being accessed after the function has returned. (They are accessed by the `write_value` function when you click the button.)

Comment: Personnaly, I tend to declare the main structure of my program inside the main, and pass its address using the `gpointer user_data` argument when connecting the signals.